# How to make a regression line in R using a normally distributed error and a uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I am very new in using R and my first task is to try and find 100 points and fit a [regression line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWC6M.png) as y=5 + 3*x + e with x uniformly distributed and e normally distributed. I have some experience with Python, but I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding R syntax.

```
xvals = runif(n = 100, min = -1, max = 1)
evals = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y<- c()
for (x in xvals) {
  for (e in evals) {
    append(y, 5 + 3*x + e)
  }
}

print(y)
```

I tried this but y seems empty. Can anyone let me know how to solve this? Also, if anyone can recommend any resources that could help besides R documentation, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arithmetic operators in R work on vectors, so you don't need the loops at all:

```
y <- 5 + 3 * xvals + evals
```

should do the trick, i.e.

```
xvals <- runif(n = 100, min = -1, max = 1)
evals <- rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y <- 5 + 3 * xvals + evals

print(y)
plot(xvals, y)
```

`y` is probably empty in your code because `append` returns the updated value, rather than updating the vector directly.  So

```
y <- append(y, 5 + 3*x + e)
```

in your loops might do what you were expecting, though you'll end up with 10,000 values (as you're doing 100 * 100 loops).

Can't think of an alternative to the R documentation off the top of my head, sorry...